# Year range selection with WPF calendar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, calendar

I'm working on a custom Calendar User Control for a WPF solution. One of the requeriments of this widget is to allow users to select a range of Years (see the picture below). I tried to set the XAML property `SelectionMode="SingleRange"`. But this only works to select a range of days.

Do you know how can I achieve this functionality?

Thanks for your time!

[image]

Comment: Do you only want to select full years? If so it might be easier to use another control. As an alternative, you could also use 2 calendar controls, 1 for the start date and one for the end date. I am not sure, but what you are trying to accomplish might be a lot of work.

Comment: Yes, I need to select full years as you can see on the picture. To use 2 calendars isn't an option for me. What kind of calendar should I use then in your opinion?

Comment: I am not familiar with a date range picker which supports what you want. In worst case scenario you have to create your own control for this functionality. But... I might be mistaken. With another control I meant, e.g.; 2 text inputs where you can type the values (not really a touch-friendly scenario), or 2 spinners.

Comment: Then it's not a feasible option for me. I need to achieve this behavior, but thank you for your time :)

Comment: No problem, and good luck. Maybe someone else is able to help you.